# related to article Get a subrange that has all the cells of a range except of a range of

Tags: excel, vba

Hi all I want to create a subrange  that excludes certain rows from that range lets say the 2nd and the 3rd row.  I have seen some answers on that site of how I can realize that, like

```
set rng = Range("B5:H20")

set subrng=rng.offset(1).resize(rng.rows.count-1)
```

or

```
Set subrng = Intersect(rng.Offset(1), rng)
```

but because I am a beginner I do not know what script goes above and underneath those commands  so that can be compatible with VBA and make it related with my worksheet.So I would like to have your help on that.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Hide the cells that you do not want to include if you are attempting a reverse-Union. Use the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) to get the visible cells.

```
dim a as long, arr as variant, r as range, rng as range
arr = array(2, 3)
for a = lbound(arr) to ubound(arr)
    range("B5:H20").rows(arr(a)).entirerow.hidden = true
next a
set rng = range("B5:H20").specialcells(xlcelltypevisible)
range("B5:H20").entirerow.hidden = false

debug.print rng.address(0,0)
```